# Extracting BeizerCurve from a PolyBezier

Tags: c#, svg

I'm trying to draw a SVG picture in a PDF. Since there's no better way to draw vectorial graphics in a PDF using iTextSharp (C#) without doing them  manually, I'm trying to do it by calling function `curveTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3).

This is my SVG:

```
<path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" fill="none" d="M 1 25 c 0,56 -0,26 21,21 -10,49 32 -15 c 3,48 -1,46 7,3 -2,36 11 -3 c 3,91 -0,68 8,17 -0,27 12 -1 c 3,01 -0,57 6,06 -2,51 9 -3 c 2,79 -0,46 6,2 0,37 9 0 c 1,97 -0,26 4,04 -1,67 6 -2 c 1,86 -0,31 4,18 -0,33 6 0 c 1,63 0,3 3,63 1,09 5 2 c 1,44 0,96 3,01 2,52 4 4 c 1,56 2,34 2,49 5,63 4 8 c 0,72 1,12 2,22 1,87 3 3 c 2,8 4,07 4,97 9,4 8 13 c 1,98 2,36 5,44 4,9 8 6 l 6 0"/>
```

The problem is I need to adapt curveTo which only accepts 3 coordinates at each time to HTML SVG norms http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCurveCommands

Which state that : "Multiple sets of coordinates may be specified to draw a polybézier". I've read that a polybézier is a set of BeizerCurves! My question is how can I parse them?

Comment: You might have to elaborate more.  The SVG spec explains exactly how to parse path definitions.

Comment: Have you tried [pdflib v9](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/new-features-in-pdflib-9/) which supports SVG imports?

Comment: This works. Too bad it's not free.

Comment: Unfortunately, reinventing the wheel requires time and last I check, you can buy time with money :)